# Get a file path from the explorer menu to a Powershell variable

Tags: windows, powershell

I need to make a API call where file upload operation is required how can I prompt user to select the file from explorer and use the path after storing in a variable. I found similar question but it only works for folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows, you can take advantage the [`OpenFileDialog` Windows Forms component](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog):

```
function Select-File {
  param([string]$Directory = $PWD)

  $dialog = [System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog]::new()

  $dialog.InitialDirectory = (Resolve-Path $Directory).Path
  $dialog.RestoreDirectory = $true

  $result = $dialog.ShowDialog()

  if($result -eq [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK){
    return $dialog.FileName
  }
}
```

Then use like so:

```
$path = Select-File
if(Test-Path $path){
  Upload-File -Path $path
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Mathias's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712649/mathias-r-jessen) answear is great, there's just one issue.

You first need to load the `System.Windows.Forms` assembly, as [this](https://4sysops.com/archives/how-to-create-an-open-file-folder-dialog-box-with-powershell/) article states!